# My Ubuntu server sometimes prevents MySQL connections until I restart the networking service, why?

Tags: networking, security, ubuntu-14.04

I run an instance of MySQL server (5.6), port 3306, on an Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) VM. Employees use a client application to interact with the database.

Periodically, I get a troubleshooting call where the user cannot connect, with the error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

The MySQL error log does not contain a refused or denied connection for the user.

Restarting the machine (not just MySQL) resolves the problem.

I've determined that this appears to be due to client machines being assigned a different IP address. I've also determined that [restarting the Ubuntu networking service](https://askubuntu.com/a/376586/200341) also resolves the problem.

I am suspicious that there is a network security feature at work here, but I am unable to figure out what it is. I would like to know:

- Can I disable this "feature" or at least configure it to trust clients on the LAN?
- Is there a way to view client machines' IP addresses that are being blocked by this mechanism?

*Edit:*

Firewall setup: `ufw` is inactive, `iptables` I believe is "factory default"

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, most setups I’ve seen use `ufw` as the default.  But that said

1. Is there a way to view client machines' IP addresses that are being blocked by this mechanism?

Yes, with ufw, it’s:

```
    sudo service ufw status
```

With iptables it’s:

```
    sudo iptables -L -v
```

2. Can I disable this "feature" or at least configure it to trust clients on the LAN?

With ufw (assuming your LAN is on 192.168.1.0/24:

```
    sudo ufw allow all from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3306
```

With iptables

```
    sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m comment --comment 'Allow all traffic from the local LAN'
```

---

As an aside, in my experience, ubuntu 14.04 has a flaky network stack.  On a couple of our servers, the network kept dying and we ended up trashing the machines in favor of centos 7.  YMMV.